# Laravel - Many To Many

Tags: php, database, laravel, many-to-many, relationship

I have two main tables with relationships many to many and a pivot table.

[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fB5dy.png)

Model Product

```
public function orders()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Order');
}
```

Model Order

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'OrderDetails');
}
```

And

```
$orders = Equipment::all();

@foreach($orders as $order)
    @foreach($order->products as $product)
        {!! $product->name !!} //it works
        // How to print the value of the quantity?
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

What should I do to print the value of the quantity?

Comment: There are few different approach you can use. I generally prefer to name this table as order_items,  and in order table use hasMany to oder_items and d HasManyThrough relations with product table. In your case, pivot table, You can use withPivot function. This article provides good insight into [pivot table](http://webnifier.com/pivot-table-many-to-many-relationships/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `->pivot->quantity`:

```
{!! $product->pivot->quantity !!}
```

Also, add `withPivot` to a ralationship:

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'OrderDetails')->withPivot('quantity');
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: How do you save multiple ids to a model? like this ```$user->roles()->sync([1 => ['expires' => true], 2, 3]);```